# EPiServer 7 GetChildren for a specific page. and list all under that page

Tags: c#, episerver

I'm having problems with EPiServer 7 trying to list childrens to a pagetype.

What I want is to get a page reference for the current page. I tried using PageReference listRoot = 
CurrentPage but it does not work.

My code looks like this:

```
    private IEnumerable<PageData> getChildren(EducationPage CurrentPage)
    {
        IEnumerable<PageData> pages = new List<PageData>(); 
        PageReference listRoot = CurrentPage;

        pages = contentLoader.GetChildren<PageData>(listRoot).OfType<PageData>();

        return pages;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need the CurrentPage.PageLink property:

```
PageReference listRoot = CurrentPage.PageLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private IEnumerable getChildren(EducationPage CurrentPage)
```

It's not wise to name something own CurrentPage since many EPi classes exposes that property (unless you actually want to override it).

```
pages = contentLoader.GetChildren<PageData>(listRoot).OfType<PageData>();
```

You don't need the OfType-part and as stated by Andreas listRoot should be a PageReference.

Comment: Thank you for your comment appreciate it!